# Set Data URI to asp:Image in code behind using ASP.Net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a relatively simple page with an asp:Image tag on it:

```
<asp:Image id="imgSelect" name="imgSelect" runat="server" src=""/>
```

I am trying to set a data URI into the image from the code behind.:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,...
```

Nothing I do is getting the image to load on the page.  I have tried:

```
imgSelect.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...";
imgSelect.DescriptionUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...";
imgSelect.Attributes["src"] = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...";
imgSelect.Attributes.Add("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,...");
```

I know my Data URI is good since I have tested it online.  I also created a simple JS method that works fine:

```
    function simpleTest() {
        var img = document.getElementById("imgSelect");
        img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."; 
    } // simpleTest
```

Is this not something that can be done with code behind or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ImageUrl` and `Attributes["src"]` should be fine. I reproduced your example with a tiny sample image and it works fine:

```
imgSelect.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAASSURBVBhXYwCC/1gwlQUZ/gMA9qoY6CSlL48AAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
```

The above displays a 5x5 black png.